# Covariant instance types on open instance delegates

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, delegates

I'm trying to create open instance delegates for methods that share a common signature, but are defined on many different and unrelated types. These methods are tagged with a custom attribute, and at runtime I lookup all the methods tagged with this attribute in order to construct delegates out of their `MethodInfo`s. For instance, given the delegate:

```
delegate void OpenActionDelegate(object instance, float someParam);
```

I would like to match the methods:

```
void Foo.SomeAction(float someParam);
void Bar.SomeOtherAction(float someParam);
```

Where `Foo` and `Bar` are completely unrelated classes. Armed with the `MethodInfo` for either method, I'd like to ultimately be able to get an open delegate like so:

```
MethodInfo fm = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("SomeAction", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
MethodInfo bm = typeof(Bar).GetMethod("SomeOtherAction", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
OpenActionDelegate fd = (OpenActionDelegate)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(OpenActionDelegate), fm);
OpenActionDelegate bd = (OpenActionDelegate)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(OpenActionDelegate), bm);
```

The problem I'm running into is the type of the explicit instance specification in the delegate. Since these methods don't have a guaranteed base type they'll be defined on, I've tried just setting `object`. But trying to bind the `MethodInfo` fails, presumably because parameter types are not covariant when binding delegates. Switching the delegate signature to have the instance param be of type `Foo` or `Bar` works for binding the corresponding `MethodInfo`.

I don't believe it's actually possible to bind an open delegate like this, because then the explicit instance param wouldn't be of the appropriate type on which to call the method. What bothers me is it *is* possible to bind a closed delegate to a `MethodInfo` of any declaring type, since that doesn't include the troublesome instance type. Case in point, I can bind closed delegates to `null` instances, and then use `GetField("_target").SetValue(del, instance)` on the delegates just before invoking them. But that's kind of hackish.

Now, in case there are alternative solutions, the reason I'm looking to do this is to avoid heap allocation and value type boxing when directly invoking the `MethodInfo`s, i.e.:

```
someActionInfo.Invoke(instance, new object[] { someParam });
```

This causes boxing of the `float` type, and the `object[]` array is allocated on the heap, both slowly generating heap garbage for an otherwise throwaway invocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameter types, including the implicit "this" parameter, clearly cannot be *covariant* and still be typesafe. Forget about instance methods for a moment and just think about static methods. If you have

```
static void Foo(Mammal m) {}
```

then you can't assign that to a delegate that takes an Animal, because the caller of that delegate could pass in a Jellyfish. You can assign it to a delegate that takes a Giraffe though, because then the caller can only pass in Giraffes, and giraffes are mammals.

In short, to be typesafe you need *contravariance*, not *covariance* on parameters.

C# does support that in a couple of ways. First off, in C# 4 you can do this:

```
Action<Mammal> aa = m=>m.GrowHair();
Action<Giraffe> ag = aa;
```

That is, conversions on the generic action type are contravariant *when the varying type parameters are reference types*.

Second, in C# 2 and above you can do this:

```
Action<Giraffe> aa = myMammal.GrowHair;
```

That is, method group conversions to delegate are contravariant in the parameter types of the method.

But the kind of covariance you want is not typesafe and therefore not supported.

Comment: That makes sense, when strictly considering the manual "this" as a parameter. But when binding the open delegate, I actually have a methodinfo with a valid declaring type -- as such, I was hoping the CLR would let me bind it and risk shooting myself in the foot if I later invoked it with an invalid type. But I guess this is not the case!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you want to create a delegate that does two things - a cast and a method call. If it were possible, you'd do it with generics:

```
public OpenActionDelegate GetDelegate<T>(MethodInfo method) {
    return (object instance, float someParam) => {
        ((T)instance).method(someParam);
    };
}
```

Unfortunately the first can only be done with generics, and the second only with reflection - so you can't combine the two!

However, if you create the delegates once and use them many times, as it seems is the case, it might be efficient to dynamically compile an expression that does it. The beauty of `Expression<T>` is that you can do *anything* with it - you're basically metaprogramming.

```
public static OpenActionDelegate GetOpenActionDelegate(Type type, string methodName) {
    MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    ParameterExpression instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
    ParameterExpression someParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(float));

    Expression<OpenActionDelegate> expression = Expression.Lambda<OpenActionDelegate>(
        Expression.Call(
            Expression.Convert(
                instance,
                type
            ),
            method,
            someParam
        ),
        instance,
        someParam
    );

    return expression.Compile();
}
```

This method will compile and return an `OpenActionDelegate` that casts its parameters to `type` and calls `methodName` on it. Here's some example usage:

```
public static void Main() {
    var someAction = GetOpenActionDelegate(typeof(Foo), "SomeAction");
    var someOtherAction = GetOpenActionDelegate(typeof(Bar), "SomeOtherAction");

    Foo foo = new Foo();
    someAction(foo, 1);

    Bar bar = new Bar();
    someOtherAction(bar, 2);

    // This will fail with an InvalidCastException
    someOtherAction(foo, 2);

    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Comment: That's actually a very elegant alternative! I didn't know about Expressions. Unfortunately the namespace isn't available the Xbox 360 version of the framework, so I can't actually use it. But it's good to know it's there.

Answer (score 1):

So as it turns out, the Xbox 360 .NET framework isn't very fond of using reflection to change non-public fields. (Read: It outright refuses to.) I imagine that's to prevent reverse-engineering some sensitive XDK information. In any event, that ruled out the little reflection hack from the question that I had ended up using.

I did, however, piece something together with generic delegates. Replace:

```
delegate void OpenActionDelegate(object instance, float someParam);
```

With:

```
delegate void OpenActionDelegate<T>(T instance, float someParam);
```

During the initial reflection, I have the `MethodInfo` for all the relevant types, meaning I can use reflection and `MakeGenericType` to create type-safe delegates for the actions without having to create them all by hand. The resulting open delegates bind flawlessly, so my delegate list is populated. However, these are stored as plain `Delegate`s, meaning I couldn't access them safely without using a prohibitive `DynamicInvoke`.

As it turns out, the action invocation method originally passed its instances as `object`s, it turns out that I *can*, in fact, make it generic in order to get the proper type for the generic delegates, and cast the `Delegate`s back to an `OpenActionDelegate<Foo>`, for instance:

```
internal static void CallAction<T>(int actionID, T instance, float param)
{
    OpenActionDelegate<T> d = (OpenActionDelegate<T>)_delegateMap[actionID];

}
```

So this way, I dodge the covariance issue altogether, get the speed of a direct delegate call and avoid boxing. The only inconvenient is that this approach won't work with inheritance, since delegates are bound to their declaring type. I'll have to considerably improve the reflection process if I ever need to support inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Because delegates predate generics, they can't do all the things that generic interfaces can.  I'm not quite clear what you're trying to do, but it seems like something that interfaces could do without need for Reflection, if you can add appropriate interfaces to the classes whose methods you want to call.  For example, if all the methods you're interested in are in IWoozable and take a `float` parameter, then you could define an interface `IWoozer` with method `void Woozle(IWoozable target, float someParam);`  One `IWoozer` implementation could be

```
void Woozle(IWoozable target, float someParam)
{
  target.Method1(someParam);
}
```

Another could be similar but use Method2, etc.  One could easily put in arbitrary code without need for delegates, and have the choice of action be independent of the choice of target.

Another thing one can do with generic interfaces which cannot be done with delegates is include open generic methods.  For example, one could have an interface

```
interface IActUpon<T>
{
  void Act(ref T target);
  void ActWithParam<PT1>(ref T target, ref PT param);
}
```

A class which holds a `T` can then expose it to a method like the above:

```
  void ActUponMyThing<ActorType>(ref ActorType Actor) where ActorType:IActUpon<T> 
  {
    Actor.Act(ref T myThing);
  }
  void ActUponMyThingWithParam<ActorType,PT>(ref IActUpon<PT> Actor, ref PT param)
    where ActorType:IActUpon<T> 
  {
    Actor.ActWithParam(ref T myThing, ref PT param);
  }
```

The use of constrained generic types for the interfaces makes it possible in some cases to use structs and avoid boxing, something which would not be possible with delegates.  Further, it's possible for open generic methods to apply multiple constraints to their generic type parameters, and call generic methods which likewise have multiple constraints, even if the classes which implement the constraints do not share a common base type.